# Firebase 6.16.1 Specified cast is not valid Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, il2cpp

I have some problems with Firebase in Unity. I'm using Unity 2020.2.0b5.3233 and Firebase App and Database 6.16.1.
I didn't have this error before, but now it appears! I left the REST API because it doesn't have a database change detection feature! What am I doing wrong?

So, here is my code:

```
public static void CheckInit()
    {
            FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("censored");
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    }

    public static void GetLastID(GetidLastCallback callback)
    {
        CheckInit();
        reference.Child("LastID")
            .ValueChanged += (object sender2, ValueChangedEventArgs e2) =>
            {
                if (e2.Snapshot != null && e2.Snapshot.ChildrenCount > 0)
                {
                    callback(e2.Snapshot.Value as idLast);
                }
            };
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class idLast
    {
        public int id;
        public idLast(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

And here are my errors:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at Database+<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<GetLastID>b__0 (System.Object sender2, Firebase.Database.ValueChangedEventArgs e2) [0x00017] in D:\UnityProjects\Troubles\Assets\Database\Database.cs:93 
  at Firebase.Database.Internal.InternalValueListener+<OnValueChangedHandler>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00030] in Z:\tmp\tmp.iLpyWKOT2N\firebase\database\client\unity\proxy\InternalValueListener.cs:53 
  at Firebase.ExceptionAggregator.Wrap (System.Action action) [0x00000] in Z:\tmp\tmp.tpC7OdQUHa\firebase\app\client\unity\src\Platform\ExceptionAggregator.cs:112 
0x00007ff6bfab34ac (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x00007ff6bfabb889 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007ff6c0f68c0c (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00007ff6c2000e43 (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00007ff6bfb28bb9 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x000001c361db5ecb (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x000001c361db5d0b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x000001c361db5a90 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
0x000001c362be5bb5 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
0x000001c36291806b (Mono JIT Code) [FirebaseLogger.cs:99] Firebase.Platform.FirebaseLogger:LogMessage (Firebase.Platform.PlatformLogLevel,string) 
0x000001c362be5223 (Mono JIT Code) [ExceptionAggregator.cs:101] Firebase.ExceptionAggregator:LogException (System.Exception) 
0x000001c362a7da13 (Mono JIT Code) [ExceptionAggregator.cs:78] Firebase.ExceptionAggregator:ThrowAndClearPendingExceptions () 
0x000001c362a7d60b (Mono JIT Code) [FirebaseHandler.cs:218] Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update () 
0x000001c362a7d443 (Mono JIT Code) [FirebaseMonoBehaviour.cs:45] Firebase.Platform.FirebaseMonoBehaviour:Update () 
0x000001c3629159e0 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ff8c437de60 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2812] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff8c4302902 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff8c430b95f (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff6bf931184 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff6bf929995 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff6bf8ecf04 (Unity) MonoBehaviour::CallMethodIfAvailable
0x00007ff6bf8ed00c (Unity) MonoBehaviour::CallUpdateMethod
0x00007ff6bedd3d78 (Unity) BaseBehaviourManager::CommonUpdate<BehaviourManager>
0x00007ff6bedddf4a (Unity) BehaviourManager::Update
0x00007ff6bf24292a (Unity) `InitPlayerLoopCallbacks'::`2'::UpdateScriptRunBehaviourUpdateRegistrator::Forward
0x00007ff6bf2241bc (Unity) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007ff6bf224293 (Unity) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007ff6bf22b259 (Unity) PlayerLoop
0x00007ff6c06277a1 (Unity) PlayerLoopController::UpdateScene
0x00007ff6c0625487 (Unity) Application::TickTimer
0x00007ff6c0f7237f (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff6c0f762e1 (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff6c2d70796 (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ff90d187034 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ff90e89cec1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

And

```
InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
Firebase.ExceptionAggregator.ThrowAndClearPendingExceptions () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.tpC7OdQUHa/firebase/app/client/unity/src/Platform/ExceptionAggregator.cs:78)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler.Update () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.tpC7OdQUHa/firebase/app/client/unity/src/Unity/FirebaseHandler.cs:217)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseMonoBehaviour.Update () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.tpC7OdQUHa/firebase/app/client/unity/src/Unity/FirebaseMonoBehaviour.cs:45)
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `Snapshot.Value` is a primitive type (`long` or `double`) so it cannot be cast to the type `idLast`. I bet you can get rid of that error using pattern matching, so replace:

```
callback(e2.Snapshot.Value as idLast);
```

with:

```
if (e2.Snapshot.Value is idLast id) {
    callback(id);
}
```

This first checks if `.Value` is of type `idLast`. Then if it is, it creates a variable named `id` of type `idLast` which I then pass into your existing `callback()` function.

With all that said, I'm pretty sure that this value will *never* be true given your snippet. That is because `Value` [can only be](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_data_snapshot_1a45e32265ebf6ad5ee66848b425e9a934) `bool`, `string`, `long`, `double`, `IDictionary<string, object>`, or `List<object>`. I don't know how your Realtime Database is structured, but if you look at the node `"LastId"` in your Firebase Console it's either a number or it contains a node called `"id"` that has a number. So if you just see a number, your code should be:

```
if (e2.Snapshot.Value is long id) {
    callback(new idLast(id));
}
```

Otherwise you should do:

```
if (e2.Snapshot.Value is IDictionary<string, object> dict) {
    long id;
    if (dict.TryGetValue("id", out id) {
        callback(new idLast(id));
    }
}
```

or you can deserialize from Json with:

```
var id = JsonUtility.FromJson<idLast>(e2.Snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
if (id != null) {
    callback(id);
}
```

Finally, every suggestion I've provided works if `.Snapshot` is not null. So leave that condition in, but you can remove  `&& e2.Snapshot.ChildrenCount > 0`.

### [Edit]

I noticed one last item of note. You only have `ValueChanged +=` but never `ValueChanged -=`. You should cache `reference.Child("LastID")` as a variable and unregister your `.ValueChanged` listener when your game ends. If you don't do this, you may run into unexpected behaviour going between play and edit mode in the Unity editor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sometime in the past I saw how "class" was made from "object". When I send data to the server, I send "idLast" and I want to receive it. I did this before, but now I can't remember how it can be done. Still, your methods are not similar to those that I did before, there I somehow immediately translated into "class". Thanks for your answer, I'll try now.

Comment: Since when can I not send for example Player player = new Player ()? What has Firebase changed?

Comment: To my knowledge, Realtime Database for Unity has always had this restriction around the `object` type (see this documentation for SetValueAsync as well: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/database-reference#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_database_reference_1af0d327eaa52ab10ee0f270507f926599 ). What you want to do will work in Firestore (with some caveats) as well as RTDB in Android, iOS, and the Web. It's a limitation only with the Unity SDK for Realtime Database.